# Compare column text pattern with defined list and return 1st match string from defined list to a new column in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Suppose I have coffee shop menu list. I want to take text and return quantity and item name.

```
menu = ['Cappuccino','Café Latte','Expresso','Macchiato ','Irish coffee ']
```

Now I want to extract number and the ordered item name matching from my menu(Any 1st match from menu)

Example Text : Bring 1 Capputino

Output dataframe :

```
      text                          Quantity                   match

     Bring 1 Capputino                 1                     Cappuccino
```

Not necessary text entered spelling will be exact same as menu so it will just return the matching pattern from menu list in match column.

I have written below code but its returning Nan in match column. Appreciate any guidance.

### Code:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import re

    def ccd():
    global df

menu = ['Cappuccino','Café Latte','Expresso','Macchiato ','Irish coffee ']

for i in range(len(menu)):
    menu[i] = menu[i].upper()


order = input('Enter a substring: ').upper()



args_dict = {'CAPUCINO':'CAPPUCCINO',
             "COFFI":"COFFEE",
             "COOKI":"COOKIE" } 
#order=order.split()

for i,j in enumerate(order):
    if j in args_dict:
        order[i]=args_dict[j]
df = pd.DataFrame({'text':[order]})
df["Quantity"] = df.text.str.extract('(\d+)')
df['match'] = df.text.str.extract('(' + '|'.join(menu) + ')')
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following:

```
import re

menu_map = {'cap': 'Cappucino',
            'caf': 'Café Latte',
            "cof": "Irish coffee",
            "cok": "Cookie",
            "cook": "Cookie"} 

order = input('Enter a substring: ')

df = pd.DataFrame({'Text': [order]})
df["Quantity"] = df.Text.str.extract('(\d+)')
df['Match'] = df.Text.str.extract('(' + '|'.join(menu_map) + ')', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
df['Replacement'] = df.Match.str.casefold().map(menu_map)
```

Result for `order == 'Bring 1 Caputino'`

```
               Text Quantity Match Replacement
0  Bring 1 Caputino        1   Cap   Cappucino
```

and `order == 'Bring 1 Caxutino'`

```
               Text Quantity Match Replacement
0  Bring 1 Caxutino        1   NaN         NaN
```

because there's no pattern in `menu_map` that catches `'Caxutino'`.

It looks to me that this is what you're essentially looking for? Since you don't want the `Replacement` column (I have only used it for transparency) you would do:

```
df['Match'] = df.Text.str.extract('(' + '|'.join(menu_map) + ')', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
df.Match = df.Match.str.casefold().map(menu_map)
```

(I don't understand what you are trying to achieve with the `for ... if ...` part.)

**EDIT**: Now that I understand the `for ... if ...` part, I'd propose the following approach:

```
args_dict = {'capu': 'Cappuccino', 'chap': 'Cappuccino', 
             'cof': 'Coffee', 'coof': 'Coffee', 'chof': 'Coffee',
             'cok': 'Cookie', 'chok': 'Cookie', 'choo': 'Cookie'}

order = order.split()
for i, word in enumerate(order):
    word = word.casefold()
    for key in args_dict:
        if word.startswith(key):
            order[i] = args_dict[key]
            break
order = ' '.join(order)
```

Or:

```
args_dict = {('capu', 'chap'): 'Cappuccino', 
             ('cof', 'coof', 'chof'): 'Coffee',
             ('cok', 'chok', 'choo'): 'Cookie'}

order = order.split()
for i, word in enumerate(order):
    word = word.casefold()
    for keys, replacement in args_dict.items():
        for key in keys:
            if word.startswith(key):
                order[i] = replacement
                break
order = ' '.join(order)
```

Comment: Thanks @Timus. Actually my bad. I wrote it in a way which is creating confusion. The output with replacement you have advised is the way I want. Only thing is that "order" string has to be compared with menu instead  of dictionary "args_dict". For time being you may think of there is no dictionary. I simply used that dictionary just to autocorrect some frequent occurring spelling mistake. Ultimate idea is to compare the corrected order string with the "menu" list and return the closest matched value

Comment: @AbhishekPrasar I see. Now it makes sense to me that you're using `.extract('(' + '|'.join(menu) + ')')`. (I think the autocorrect dict is a good idea, though.) I guess you should remove the `for ... if ...`  part and try it again with your solution?

Comment: Yes sir. I am trying with dictionary approach of setting my menu with multiple wrong spelt word with custom menu name. If that works for me I will eliminate the list completely and proceed with your suggested approach.

Comment: One small doubt "can I pass a list multiple wrong spelt word to one word inside dictionary. Like if user say 'capu' or 'capi' , it should be referred to "Chappucino". I know to do it one by one assigning inside dictionary. But is there a way to pass it one time? That will actually solve my purpose

Comment: @AbhishekPrasar You can't use lists as dictionary keys (they are not _hashable_), but you could use tuples (I've added such a version).